# Camel route broke when receive large data

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a route camel which uses camel-undertow and camel-http4 to be used as gateway between two distinct web applications.

The route works fine when last endpoint response has small size. However when last endpoint response has large size I receive truncated data.

Example of correct response:

```
{ 
    "field1": "something", 
    "field2": "something", 
    "field3": "something" 
}
```

Example of incorrect (truncated) response:

```
{ 
    "field1": "something", 
    "field2": "something", 
    "field3": "something", 
    "fiel
```

This is my route:

```
from("undertow://0.0.0.0:8080/mec?httpMethodRestrict=POST,GET") //receive only POST and GET http methods
.to("http4://something/endpoint?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&copyHeaders=false");
```

The endpoint "http4://something/endpoint" response an JSON. As I already said, when response of "http4://something/endpoint" is small everything works fine. However when is large the route broke.

I think there is some buffer that I need configure in this components but I did not found anything.

Comment: I appended a ".log" after ".to("...")" and get complete response but when I make a request in postman I receive truncated response

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: Hi Claus only now I saw your comment. I was not getting empty body, but instead truncated body. I tried stream caching and change CamelCachedOutputStreamThreshold and CamelCachedOutputStreamBufferSize but has no effect.